# Does $xy=1$ imply $yx=1$ in the real Clifford Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I feel it true that $xy=1$ implies $yx=1$ in the real Clifford Algebra $C_n$ (with respect to the quadratic form  $Q=-x_1^2-……-x_n^2$), but I cannot prove it. Is it true?

Comment: OK, it's really true and I know how to porve it, even it is a little complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in a matrix algebra over a field, so it is true in your Clifford algebra, because —being semisimple— it is a direct product of matrix algebras.

*N.B.* This property is called «Dedekind-finiteness».

Answer (score 1):

It is true since
$$xy=x\cdot y+x\wedge y=1$$
implies $x\cdot y=1$ and $x\wedge y=0$, hence
$$yx=y\cdot x+y\wedge x=x\cdot y-x\wedge y=1$$